# JTabbedPane in Nimbus with different colors for each tab

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, nimbus

I want to create a JTabbedPane using the Nimbus Look and Feel that has different colors for each tab. I have found multiple ways to change the colors, but as far as I can tell, these technique apply globally to all tabs with a certain state (such as changing all tabs with `TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Enabled].backgroundPainter` to be the same color)

Two useful SO links I have found (close but not quite the answer to my question):

[Override Swing Nimbus L&F primary color per component instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922368/override-swing-nimbus-lf-primary-color-per-component-instance)

[Set the Background Color for JTabbedPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445565/set-the-background-color-for-jtabbedpane)

Below is a mockup image of what I'd like to achieve.

[image]

*edit - sorry forgot to include demo program source code. (This doesn't create the coloring but otherwise launches a new window with the appropriate tab pane.):

```
public class TabbedPaneExample extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for(javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.
                    getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TabbedPaneExample().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public TabbedPaneExample(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTabbedPane pane = new JTabbedPane();
        pane.addTab("Blue", new JLabel("Blue tab"));
        pane.addTab("Red", new JLabel("Red tab"));
        pane.addTab("Yellow", new JLabel("Yellow tab"));

        this.add(pane);

        pack();
    }
}
```

*Edit - In regards to zilk's answer below - it does not appear to work.  Extending `BasicTabbedPaneUI` causes the Nimbus specific rendering to be lost. In order to keep the Nimbus rendering, `SynthTabbedPaneUI` needs to be extended. However, `SynthTabbedPaneUI` doesn't call `paintTabBackground`, instead it calls `paintTabArea`, which is both a protected method and an overloaded private helper method. It looks like all the logic occurs in the private helper method. I can't reproduce that private method in my own code because of private instance variables in `SynthTabbedPaneUI` and package private code in `SynthContext` which is used by `paintTabArea`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set new UI that is extended BasicTabbedPaneUI for your tabbedpane. After that you should just override the paintTabBackground method. Try this codes

```
pane.setUI(new BasicTabbedPaneUI(){
        @Override
        protected void paintTabBackground(Graphics g, int tabPlacement,int tabIndex, int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean isSelected){
           //default backcolor 
           Color bg = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;

           switch(tabIndex){
             case 0:
                   bg = Color.BLUE;  
                   break;   
              case 1: 
                   bg = Color.YELLOW;
                   break;
              case 2: 
                   bg = Color.RED;
                   break;
               }
            g.setColor(bg);

           switch (tabPlacement){
              case SwingConstants.TOP:
                   g.fillRect(x + 1, y + 1, w - 1, h - 1);
                   break;
              case SwingConstants.BOTTOM:
                   g.fillRect(x, y, w - 1, h - 1);
                   break;
              case SwingConstants.LEFT:
                   g.fillRect(x + 1, y + 1, w - 1, h - 2);
                   break;
              case SwingConstants.RIGHT:
                   g.fillRect(x, y + 1, w - 1, h - 2);
                   break;
               }
    }
 });
```

Edit:
Here is my codes result
[image]

P.S: Do not forget this

```
pane.setOpaque(true);
```

Comment: This appears to not work for Nimbus only. Extending `BasicTabbedPaneUI` causes the Nimbus specific rendering to be lost. In order to keep the Nimbus rendering, `SynthTabbedPaneUI` needs to be extended. However, `SynthTabbedPaneUI` doesn't call `paintTabBackground`, instead it calls `paintTabArea`, which is a protected method and a private helper method. It looks like all the logic occurs in the private method, and I can't reproduce that because of private instance variables. I'll update my answer w/ more information.

Comment: I don't understand why you need this for only Nimbus. And what do you actually mean about "loosing/keeping Nimbus rendering " ? 
My codes work properly as your mockup

Comment: Our applications use the Nimbus L&F. When extending `BasicTabbedPaneUI`, the `JTabbedPane` takes on the appearance of the Metal L&F (and it no longer has the Nimbus L&F). This makes the `JTabbedPane` look out of place in our application. Here is an image that demonstrates the normal Nimbus `JTabbedPane` side by side with the custom `JTabbedPane` using `BasicTabbedPaneUI`. http://i.imgur.com/Lv2lmHK.png Note how the appearance of the corners, borders, gradients, and selection highlight appear different. I can't figure out how to achieve the different tab colors and keep the Nimbus L&F.