# How can i change jtabbedpane selected tab background color

Tags: java, background-color, jtabbedpane

I tried most of the things to do this,using helps from this site,there have more related post about this question,but any of that questions not helped to me.

[image]

I need to change `jtabbedpane` selected tab background color.i used this code to that,but nothing will happen

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class TestTabcolor extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public TestTabcolor() {
        initComponents();
        UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", Color.Red);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestTabcolor().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

can anyone tell me how can i change selected tab color :) Thank you

**Update:**
please don't set this question as duplicated,because that related questions not solved my problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the Background Color for JTabbedPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445565/set-the-background-color-for-jtabbedpane)

Comment: If you don't think your question is a duplicate, you could explain how it differs.

Comment: @Robert http://stackoverflow.com/a/2512232/7185884 i tried this solution also,but its not work,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call this `UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", Color.Red);` **befor**e `initComponents();`

Comment: there is no `initComponents()` function using intellij Idea