# Change the background color behind the tabs of a JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

The problem is referred to in the question. I intend to change the color of the area marked with an 'X' in the image below but I don't know how to do it. I've tried to change the `JTabbedPane` background but it didn't work.

I apologize in advance for any English mistakes I may have made.

#### Minimal reproducible example

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TabbedPane Error"); // creates 2. JFrame
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.setBackground(Color.RED);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Browser",new JPanel());
        tabbedPane.addTab("Asset Notifications",new JPanel());
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500,200));
        frame.add(tabbedPane);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image: Example image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change background color of JTabbedPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752037/how-to-change-background-color-of-jtabbedpane)

Comment: Does `pane.setBackground(Color.RED)` not work? (Where `pane` is a `JTabbedPane`)

Comment: I've tried it that way and it didn't work. I will add the methods I have tried to the question.

Comment: Instead of adding "the methods" post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue and your approaches to solve it.

Comment: I will do it @Frakcool

Comment: I added the minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. You need to specify your own custom UI.

1. You need to extend the `BasicTabbedPaneUI` class and override `paint`.
2. Then you can set the UI:

```java
tabbedPane.setUI(new CustomTabbedUI(Color.RED));
```

This really [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11275295/1762224) I dug up was partially correct. Obviously it was incomplete.

---

#### Launcher.java

```java
package q60855752;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new App());
    }
}
```

#### App.java

```java
package q60855752;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class App extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    public App() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.setUI(new CustomTabbedUI(Color.RED));

        // Modified: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html
        addPanel(tabbedPane, "Tab 1", "Panel #1", "Does nothing", KeyEvent.VK_1, null);
        addPanel(tabbedPane, "Tab 2", "Panel #2", "Does twice as much nothing", KeyEvent.VK_2, null);
        addPanel(tabbedPane, "Tab 3", "Panel #3", "Still does nothing", KeyEvent.VK_3, null);
        addPanel(tabbedPane, "Tab 4", "Panel #4", "Panel #4 (has a preferred size of 410 x 50).", KeyEvent.VK_4, new Dimension(410, 50));

        add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("App");
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
        frame.setContentPane(new App());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected void addPanel(JTabbedPane tabbedPane, String title, String content, String tooltip, int mnemonic, Dimension dimensions) {
        JComponent panel = createPanel(title);
        if (dimensions != null) panel.setPreferredSize(dimensions);
        tabbedPane.addTab(content, null, panel, tooltip);
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(tabbedPane.getTabCount() - 1, mnemonic);
    }

    protected JComponent createPanel(String text) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
        JLabel filler = new JLabel(text);
        filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        panel.add(filler);
        return panel;
    }
}
```

#### CustomTabbedUI.java

```java
package q60855752;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI;
import java.awt.*;

public class CustomTabbedUI extends BasicTabbedPaneUI {
    private Color backgroundColor;

    public CustomTabbedUI(Color backgroundColor) {
        super();
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(Color backgroundColor) {
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        Rectangle bounds = tabPane.getBounds();
        g.setColor(this.backgroundColor);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height);

        super.paint(g, c); // Call parent...
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't want to extend the BasicTabbedPaneUI. That is only the basic UI for your LAF. For example the MetalTabbedPaneUI will extend that class to add the custom metal LAF code.

Answer (score 0):

> I intend to change the color of the area marked with an 'X'

The only "X" I see is in the title bar of the frame. You can't change that using Swing.

If you want to change the background behind where the tabs are painted then you need to change the background of the component you add the tabbed pane to. In your example you can use:

```
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED) 
frame.add(tabbedPane);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED)` work?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, much easier. Don't know what I was thinking.